# How to pass configuration to a connected component in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have container components and a generic presentational component.

I want to connect the containers with the latter and pass a config object which is not derived from the state, (don't want to just stick it in mapStateToProps). Any ideas how to do this? thanks

Comment: You need to pass the config object as a property down through each component.

Comment: Pass a prop in from the App.jsx (or whatever you call it) level?

Comment: Do you want the config object to connect with the state?

Answer (score 0):

Pass props as for any React component. 
In [mapStateToProps](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#arguments): use the second argument to handle the case in which you doesn't want redux state overiding the passed props.